# React redux update nested Object property value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm try to make fields validation in mine project and here is mine fields state model

```
const initialState = {
    fields: {
        title: {
            value: '',
            isCorrectValue: false
        },
        amount: {
            value: '',
            isCorrectValue: false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to update mine field state isCorrectValue if value.length lower then 1 here is regex what I'm using to check fields value length

```
const checkValue = (value) => {
    return (/^.{1,}$/).test(value);
};
```

here is mine reducer where I'm trying to update mine state cannot understand why i cannot to grasp

```
isCorrectValue
```

```
export default function fieldsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ONCHANGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                fields: {
                    ...state.fields,
                    [`${action.payload.name}`]: {
                        ...[`${action.payload.name}`],
                        value: action.payload.value
                    }
                }
            }
        case VALIDATEFIELDS:
            return {
                ...state,
                fields: Object.keys(state.fields).reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    !checkTitle(state.fields[curr].value)
                        ? Object.assign(acc, state.fields,
                            {
                                curr: { ...state.fields, [state.fields[curr].isCorrectValue]: !state.fields[curr].isCorrectValue }
                            }
                        )
                        : acc = state.fields;
                    return acc;
                }, {})
            }
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

here is mine component where reducer is working

```
const AddTransaction = () => {
    const state = useSelector(state => state.fieldsReducer);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    console.log(state.fields.title.isCorrectValue)

    return (
        <div className='add-transaction-wrapper'>
            <div className='add-expense-inputs-wrapper'>
                <TextField
                    id='title'
                    label='title'
                    value={state.fields.title.value}
                    onChange={e => dispatch(onHandleChange(e, e.target.id))}
                />
                <TextField
                    id="amount"
                    label="expense amount"
                    type="number"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                    }}
                    value={state.fields.amount.value}
                    onChange={e => dispatch(onHandleChange(e, e.target.id))}
                    error={state.fields.amount.isCorrectValue}
                />
                <button onClick={() => dispatch(fieldsValidation())}>click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in your reducer:

```js
//not part of your reducer
const state = {
  fields: {
      title: {
          value: '',
          isCorrectValue: false
      },
      amount: {
          value: '',
          isCorrectValue: false
      }
  }
}
//just a sample action
const action = {
  payload:{
    name:'amount',
    value:true
  }
}
//this is what you should do in your reducer
const newState = {
  ...state,
  fields: {
      ...state.fields,
      [action.payload.name]: {
          ...state.fields[action.payload.name],
          value: action.payload.value
      }
  }
}
console.log('new state:',newState)
```

VALIDATEFIELDS is kind of a mess and I have no idea what you want to do there.